# shell script problem with using the operators

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am comparing two strings using the `levenshtein distance` algorithm. I got the PHP implementation of the algorithm from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#PHP). I am calling this php implementation from my shell script as below.

```
levenshtein_return=$(php levensh.php "String1" "String2")
```

The `levenshtein_return` variable contains the value as 1 now as there is a single character difference.

Now, before inserting the value as such in database tables, I need to perform some arithmetic operations using this variable. I am trying to implement as,

```
table_value=$( expr( 1/ ( 1 + $levenshtein_return ) ) )
```

However, if I use the above syntax I am getting an error as,

```
line 52: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
```

How can I change the expr statement so that I can get the actual value for the `table_value` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `expr` in this case, try this:

```
table_value=$(( 1 / (1+$levenshtein_return) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems there.

In:

```
table_value=$( expr( 1/ ( 1 + $levenshtein_return ) ) )
```

The `(` and `)` characters are special to the shell so has to be escaped. And it's the `expr` command you want to run, not the `expr(` command. Also you must pass operators and operands as separate arguments to `expr`.

```
table_value=$(expr '(' 1 / "(" 1 + "$levenshtein_return" \) ')' )
```

(above showing the different ways you can quote the `(` and `)` characters).

Now as [@Gnouc has shown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115635/22565), `expr` is no longer necessary for arithmetic evaluation as all modern POSIX shells have a `$((...))` built-in operator for that.

Now, except with `zsh` and `ksh93`, neither `expr` nor `$((...))` do floating point arithmetic. So in both:

```
table_value=$(expr 1 / "(" 1 + "$levenshtein_return" ")" )
```

and

```
table_value=$((1 / (1 + $levenshtein_return)))
```

The value will be integer, so typically either 0 or 1.

If you did meant to have 1 if the strings are the same and 0 if they are different (but then, you don't need to calculate a distance if all you want to do is check that two strings are the same), then you'd have written:

```
table_value=$((!$levenshtein_return))
```

In `ksh93` or `zsh`, if you wanted a floating point value, you'd write:

```
table_value=$((1. / (1 + $levenshtein_return)))
```

In other shells, and POSIXly, if you need floating point arithmetic, you typically call a command that can  do it like `awk`, `bc` or... `php`.

Here, as you're already invoking `php`, you might as well make it do the final calculation as well. If using `awk`, note that `awk` can also do the Levenshtein distance calculation easily:

```
table_value=$(awk '
    function min(x, y) {
      return x < y ? x : y
    }
    function lev(s,t) {
      m = length(s)
      n = length(t)

      for(i=0;i<=m;i++) d[i,0] = i
      for(j=0;j<=n;j++) d[0,j] = j

      for(i=1;i<=m;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++) {
          c = substr(s,i,1) != substr(t,j,1)
          d[i,j] = min(d[i-1,j]+1,min(d[i,j-1]+1,d[i-1,j-1]+c))
        }
      }

      return d[m,n]
    }

    BEGIN {print 1 / (1 +lev(ARGV[1], ARGV[2])); exit}' String1 String2
)
```

Comment: I was trying to do in shell script but did not know floating point calculation was not available in it. Your `awk` suggestion is working. Instead of calling a php script from my shell script, I can include the awk code inside the shell script itself. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ramesh, note that you can embed php code as well with `php -r`: `php -r 'function lev...; echo lev(argv[1],argv[2])' String1 String2`

Comment: oh I was not aware of that. I used to invoke the php script located in the same location as my shell script using the `php filename` command.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not documented and not guaranteed by POSIX, it seems that because POSIX requires shells to handle C constants and many of the same operators C does, they seem to source all of the rest of the simple C integer math operators as well, including ternary tests and assignments:

```
% a=abc
% b=abcd
% t=1 ; f=0
% echo $((r=${#a}>${#b}?t:f)) ; echo $r
> 0 
> 0
% echo $((r=${#a}<${#b}?t:f)) ; echo $r
> 1
> 1
```

I've just tested the above basic example in zsh, bash, bash's sh, and dash. All behaved correctly and identically.

Comment: They also all seem to handle bitwise math, like | & ^ << >> but that stuff baffles me so it's in a comment.