# Decoding bash script

Tags: shell-script

Have following line in bash script, parsing input arguments:

```
((10#$2 > 0)) 2>/dev/null && shift 2 || shift
```

Basically it helps handling parameters with optional integer subparameter. Like:

```
-x 100 -y

-x -y
```

Could you explain how it works.

Comment: You can get the same result with much less fuss if you shift ${2+$(((10#$2>0)+1))}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line checks whether the second positional parameter is greater than `0`.  If the condition is true then it shifts the positional parameters 3, 4, ... to 1, 2, ...  If the condition is false then it shifts the positional parameters 2, 3, ... to 1, 2, ...

Constants with leading zero are interpreted as octal numbers.  Saying `10#$2` causes the positional parameter `$2` to be interpreted as a decimal.  You might also want to refer to [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

As such, `((10#$2 > 0))` checks if the second positional parameter represented in base 10 is greater than 0.  `2>/dev/null` causes any errors resulting from this test to be redirected to `/dev/null`. See [Bash Arithmetic Expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) for more on the `#` operator.

`&&` and `||` are conditional constructs.  So if the condition is true then `shift 2` is executed else `shift` is executed.

> `expression1 && expression2`
>
> True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
>
> `expression1 || expression2`
>
> True if either expression1 or expression2 is true.

As an example, refer to the following:

```
$ ((10>42)) && echo greater || echo smaller    # Condition is false so the `echo smaller` expression is evaluated
smaller
$ ((100>42)) && echo greater || echo smaller   # Condition is true so the `echo greater` expression is evaluated
greater
```

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> `((...))`
>
> ```
> (( expression ))
> ```
>
> The arithmetic expression is evaluated according to the rules described below (see Shell Arithmetic). If the value of the expression
>   is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.
>   This is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> let "expression"
> ```

Comment: Perhaps an example would help illustrate this better, it's a little hard to follow and the OP appears new to all this. Explain what's going on with the `10#$2` since that's the most magical part.

Comment: @slm I was about to add parts.  Sorry didn't add everything to begin with.

Comment: NP - I do the same, sorry should've waited 8-)

Comment: As for the last - n > n && echo || echo , you can also use a ternary expression: t=20 ; f=10 ; s=1 ; b=2 ; echo $((tern=s<b?t:f)) ; echo $tern - 20\n20 http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119314/52934